# How to write validation for below code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here, In my code First name and Last name fields placed side by side how to write a validation for that 2 fields i tried but am not getting correct.I attached image and my code below

jQuery code:

```
 jQuery(function(){

            jQuery("#fName").validate({

                expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,30}$/)) return true; else return false;",

                message: "Please enter the First Name Last Name"

            });
        });
```

signup.html

```
   <div class="form-fullname">
        <input class ="first-name"type="text" id="fName" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required="">

        <input class="last-name" type="text" id="lName" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required="">
   </div>
```

The full page is an error image.

Error:
in this signup form when am entered numbers in first name it should show error message at below, but it is showing beside first name as shown in picture. So can you tell me how can i get error message in below.

Comment: To get the error message below, just place the corresponding tag in a separate div just like how you might have done for text boxes showing email, username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use test function on the regular expression in JavaScript to know whether the input is in valid format.

Use css function to display or hide the error messages.

If you want to show error for first name field when last name field is focused you can write an on focus event in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var NAME_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,30}$/;

  $('#signupBtn').click(signupBtnClick);
  
  $('input[name="lastname"]').focus(lastNameOnFocus);
  
  function signupBtnClick() {
    validateFirstName();
    validateLastName();
  }
  
  function lastNameOnFocus() {
    validateFirstName();
  }
  
  function validateFirstName() {
    var firstName = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
    
    if(NAME_REGEX.test(firstName)) {
     $('#firstnameerror').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
     $('#firstnameerror').css('display', 'block');
    } 
  }
  
  function validateLastName () {
    var lastName = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
    
    if(NAME_REGEX.test(lastName)) {
     $('#lastnameerror').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
     $('#lastnameerror').css('display', 'block');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Sign Up</h3>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  <span id="firstnameerror" style="color: red; display: none;">First Name is required</span>  
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 1%;">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  <span id="lastnameerror" style="color: red; display: none;">Last Name is required</span>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 2%;">
  <button type="button" id="signupBtn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the regex on input tag Instead:

```
<form action="register_page">
    <div class="form-fullname">
        <input class ="first-name" type="text" id="fName" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" pattern="^\w{2,30}$" required>

        <input class="last-name" type="text" id="lName" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" pattern="^\w{2,30}$" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Note that you can use \w on regex instead of [a-zA-Z]. This way you don't need jquery validation in this case.

Comment: If first name is empty when i click last name it should show error msg

Comment: It won't show an error message right when you leave first name input but it will display an error message when user try to submit. And, besides it will not allow user to go any further unless he fills up the inputs properly, it automatically auto focus the required input for you.